# Material design icon with underscore in its name doesn't work with Vuetify

Tags: icons, material-design, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify and everything works well apart from the icons when they have an underscore in their name.
For example:

```
<v-icon>mdi-how_to_vote</v-icon>
```

doesn't work, but

```
<v-icon>mdi-home</v-icon>
```

does.

Does anybody have a clue?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, actually they changed the names containing an underscore... It's confusing because https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline exists but you should search here: https://materialdesignicons.com/